# Supplement a Records Columns in Room

Tags: android, android-room

I am fairly new to Android Room and SQLite in general, so sorry if this is a simple question.

I am getting data from a API that I'd like to insert into a database so it's accessible when the device is offline.

Depending on the endpoint of the API, some fields of my Data objects may be null (Think a summary with just the basic fields versus a fully detailed object with all fields)

To keep the database clean, I'd like to update the entries, but only the columns that are not null (eg. that I have new values for) and keep the rest of the columns untouched.

Here are some example classes to clarify:

**Person**

```
@Entity(tableName = "person", indices = {
        @Index(value = "id", unique = true)
})
public class Person {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;

    public String name;

    public String description;
}
```

**Example:**

```
// create db
RoomDB db = RoomDB.create(ctx);

// create some sample objects
final Person p2 = new Person(2, "Peter", null);

// insert them into the db
db.personDao().insert(p2);

// create a updated peter that likes spiders
// but has no name (as a example)
final Person newPeter = new Person(2, null, "Peter likes spiders");

// and update him
db.personDao().updateNonNull(newPeter);

// now we read him back
final Person peter = db.personDao().getById(2);
```

In this example, the desired values of 'peter' would be:

```
id = 2
name = "Peter"
description = "Peter likes spiders"
```

However, using Room's @Update or @Insert i can only get this:

```
id = 2
name = null
description = "Peter likes spiders"
```

The only way i found to achive this would be to manuall get the object and supplement the values like so:

```
@Transaction
public void updateNonNull(Person newPerson) {
    final Person oldPerson = getById(newPerson.id);
    if (oldPerson == null) {
        insert(newPerson);
        return;
    }
    
    if (newPerson.name == null)
        newPerson.name = oldPerson.name;

    if (newPerson.description == null)
        newPerson.description = oldPerson.description;

    update(newPerson);
}
```

However, that would result in quite a bit of code with bigger objects...
So my question, is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:**

After some Testing with the SQL by @Priyansh Kedia, i found that those functions indeed work as intended and do so at a higher performance than java.

However, as a SQL statement would have required me to write huge queries, i decided to use a Reflection based solution, as can be seen below.
I only did so because the function isn't called regularly, so the lower performance won't matter too much.

```java
    /**
     * merge two objects fields using reflection.
     * replaces null value fields in newObj with the value of that field in oldObj
     * <p>
     * assuming the following values:
     * oldObj: {name: null, desc: "bar"}
     * newObj: {name: "foo", desc: null}
     * <p>
     * results in the "sum" of both objects: {name: "foo", desc: "bar"}
     *
     * @param type   the type of the two objects to merge
     * @param oldObj the old object
     * @param newObj the new object. after the function, this is the merged object
     * @param <T>    the type
     * @implNote This function uses reflection, and thus is quite slow.
     * The fastest way of doing this would be to use SQLs' ifnull or coalesce (about 35% faster), but that would involve manually writing a expression for EVERY field.
     * That is a lot of extra code which i'm not willing to write...
     * Besides, as long as this function isn't called too often, it doesn't really matter anyway
     */
    public static <T> void merge(@NonNull Class<T> type, @NonNull T oldObj, @NonNull T newObj) {
        // loop through each field that is accessible in the target type
        for (Field f : type.getFields()) {
            // get field modifiers
            final int mod = f.getModifiers();

            // check this field is not status and not final
            if (!Modifier.isStatic(mod)
                    && !Modifier.isFinal(mod)) {
                // try to merge
                // get values of both the old and new object
                // if the new object has a null value, set the value of the new object to that of the old object
                // otherwise, keep the new value
                try {
                    final Object oldVal = f.get(oldObj);
                    final Object newVal = f.get(newObj);

                    if (newVal == null)
                        f.set(newObj, oldVal);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    Log.e("Tenshi", "IllegalAccess in merge: " + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in-built method in room to do this

What you can do is, put check in the query for your update method.

```
@Query("UPDATE person SET name = (CASE WHEN :name IS NOT NULL THEN :name ELSE name END), description = (CASE WHEN :description IS NOT NULL THEN :description ELSE description END) WHERE id = :id")
Person update(id: Int, name: String, description: String)
```

We have written the update query for SQL which checks if the inserted values are null or not, and if they are null, then the previous values are retained.

Comment: It would be simpler/more concise to use  `SET name = coalesce(:name,name)` .... or `ifnull(:name,name)` rather than `CASE WHEN .... THEN ....  END`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this tip, I didn't know SQL had such a function. However, this would have required quite a bit of code, so i decided to use a function similar to my original idea, but using reflection.